# Conflict between two addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have two addEventListner methods. The first calls the function activateItem() (it adds a red background on a list item on click) and the second calls the function addItem() (it add a list element when we click on the button).

From the time addItem() is called once, activateItem() can no longer be called and I don't understand why.

**HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title" > Clik a list item to replace this text.</h1>
  <button id=button>Add new item</button>
  <ul id=list>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS code:**

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var unorderedList = document.getElementById('list');
var newItemCounter = 0;

for(i=0;i < list.length; i++){
  list[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem);
}

function activateItem(){
  title.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

button.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem(){
  newItemCounter++;
  unorderedList.innerHTML += "<li>New item " + newItemCounter +  "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `innerHTML`, use proper DOM manipulation methods instead.

Comment: When you overwrite `unorderedList.innerHTML`, it's replacing all of the content with new elements that don't have events. Avoid `.innerHTML`. It's the sloppy way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this . Initiate the `list click` event inside the `addItem()`

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var unorderedList = document.getElementById('list');
var newItemCounter = 0;

function activateItem() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem);
}
button.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem() {
  newItemCounter++;
  unorderedList.innerHTML += "<li>New item " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title"> Clik a list item to replace this text.</h1>
  <button id=button>Add new item</button>
  <ul id=list>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the comment in the code below

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var unorderedList = document.getElementById('list');
var newItemCounter = 0;

for(i=0;i < list.length; i++){
  list[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem);
}

function activateItem(){
  title.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

button.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem(){
  newItemCounter++;
  ///HERE's the modification, i suppose the innerHtml +=  was recreating the whole thing inside thus the listeners were lost
  var node = document.createElement("LI");                 
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("New item " + newItemCounter);         
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              
  unorderedList.appendChild(node); 
  node.addEventListener("click", activateItem);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title" > Clik a list item to replace this text.</h1>
  <button id=button>Add new item</button>
  <ul id=list>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
    <li>Fourth item</li>
    <li>Fifth item</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```